# Why there is no increment in the range of a loop, with its range being length of the loop,even though the length gets incremented inside the loop?

Tags: for-loop, python-3.7

I am a beginner and I was trying this Fibonacci series on my own, but why is the value of variable b=len(e)+5  not getting incremented even if the length of the list grows! Why it does not affect the range of for loop.

```
e=[0,1]
a=1
b=len(e)+5
n=int(input('enter a no.'))
for i in range(a,b):
    print(b)
    if n<=len(e):
        print(e[n-1])
        break
    else:
        e.append(e[i-1]+e[i])
        try:
            if e[len(e)-1]==e[n-1]:
                print(e[n-1])
                break
        except:
            pass
```

I hope I was clear with the question. I'm welcome to any suggestions that are reasonably simple since I'm a beginner. If there's anything I'm doing horribly wrong, please do point that out as well.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey @Jayasri Palanisamy the reason why value of `b` is not being incremented is because it is executed only once. When `b= len(e)+5 = 7`.

```
e=[0,1]
a=1
n=int(input('enter a no.'))
b = len(e)+n
for i in range(a,b):
print(b)
if n<=len(e):
    print(e[n-1])
    break
else:
    e.append(e[i-1]+e[i])
    try:
        if e[len(e)-1]==e[n-1]:
            print(e[n-1])
            break
    except:
        pass
```

This will get you the correct answer but this also is not a good solution (I mean there is a way to do the same and is simpler).

Comment: @Roberto Caboni I  am comfortable with the answer. but why does the range not getting modified,when" else: e.append(e[i-1]+e[i])",here the length of the list is altered in the loop

Comment: See like i have said value of `b` is only executed once during the start of the program. The Python interpreter looks at the top of the code then moves to the bottom in a sequential way. unless you use a control statement (like for or while)it will not be executed more than once.

Answer (score 0):

simple code

```
e = [0,]
a, b = 0, 1
n = int(input('enter a no.'))
for i in range(1, n):
    a, b = b, a + b
    e.append(a)

print(e[n-1], e)
```

result is

```
21 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

Comment: I am comfortable with the ans. but why does the range not getting modified,when   else:
        e.append(e[i-1]+e[i]),here the length of the list is altered in the loop